# Regex between last slash and next space in a set of strings in Bash

Tags: regex, grep, pcre

I've a bunch of strings in an output

```
adadds/asdsd/foo aeee/ggdgg/bar aff/ggg/ddafs/afdf/doo
```

From this I need the following list

```
foo
bar
doo
```

I tried the following but in vain:

```
(?<=\/)(.*?)(?=\s)
```

and

```
([/])(.*?)(?=\s)
```

Comment: Maybe you could try `\w+(?!\S)`

Comment: Wow, thanks, this works too!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `gnu grep`:

```sh
s='adadds/asdsd/foo aeee/ggdgg/bar aff/ggg/ddafs/afdf/doo'
grep -oP '[^/\s]+(?=\s|$)' <<< "$s"

foo
bar
doo
```

**RegEx Details:**

- `[^/\s]+`: Match 1+ of any char that is not `/` and not a whitespace
- `(?=\s|$)`: Make sure we have either a whitespace or end of line ahead of current position

If `gnu grep` is not available try this `awk`:

```
awk '{for (i=1; i<=NF; ++i) {sub(/.*\//, "", $i); print $i}}' <<< "$s"
```

Answer (score 2):

With GNU grep, you can use

```
grep -oP '/\K\w++(?!/)' <<< "$s"
grep -oP '/\K\w++(?!/)' file
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/CLObrt/1)

*Details*:

- `-o` - extract matches, not whole lines matching the pattern
- `P` - enable PCRE regex engine
- `/` - `/` char
- `\K` - omit the matched `/` from the match
- `\w++` - one or more word chars matched possessively
- `(?!/)` - no `/` allowed immediately on the right (fail the match and do not re-match with `\w++` if there is a `/`).

With `awk`:

```
awk '{for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {sub(/.*\//,"",$i); print $i}}' <<< "$s"
awk '{for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {sub(/.*\//,"",$i); print $i}}' file
```

That is, iterate over all whitespace-separated fields, remove all up to the last `/` (including it) and print the remaining field value(s).